# Property 'getReadableSchedule' is missing in type

Tags: typescript

How do I populate a typed array where the type being populated has a function (getReadableSchedule)? If I remove the function this works. Is this failing because of the way i'm assigning the the array elements?

> ERROR in src/app/mock-extracts.ts(3,14): error TS2322: Property 'getReadableSchedule' is missing in type '{ id: number; name: string; description: string; client: string; vendor: string; extractType: str...'.

```js
export class Extract {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  client: string;
  vendor: string;
  extractType: string;
  path: string;
  sentDate: string;
  sentTo: string;
  lastRun: string;
  nextRun: string;
  schedule: string;

  getReadableSchedule(): string {
    return "<return readable cronjob schedule>";
  }
}
```

```js
import { Extract } from "./extract";

export const EXTRACTS: Extract[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Find Barb",
    description: "Find Barb in the unspide down.",
    client: "Tower, Inc",
    vendor: "Vendy",
    extractType: "Normal",
    sentDate: "Today",
    path: "//outside",
    sentTo: "",
    lastRun: "",
    nextRun: "",
    schedule: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Rescue Will",
    description: "Give Will a hair cut.",
    client: "Tower, Inc",
    vendor: "Vendy",
    extractType: "Normal",
    sentDate: "Today",
    path: "//outside",
    sentTo: "",
    lastRun: "",
    nextRun: "",
    schedule: ""
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Sooth Harry's Scar",
    description: "Put Robitussin on Harry's scar.",
    client: "Tower, Inc",
    vendor: "Turkish Barn, LLC",
    extractType: "Normal",
    sentDate: "Today",
    path: "//outside",
    sentTo: "",
    lastRun: "",
    nextRun: "",
    schedule: ""
  }
];
```

Comment: Well, you declared that Extract instances are supposed to have a getReadableSchedule method, but none of the objects in the array has this method. So, in short, you're trying to put apples in an array of oranges.

Comment: @JBNizet but you don't populate methods, unless I'm just not understanding how this array is populating a list of objects.

Comment: Yes, you do. Unless of course the objects are actual instances of the class: `new Extract()`

Comment: I'm very new to ts so bare with me. If I'm giving values to properties why wouldn't these entries be instances of class `Extract`?

Comment: Because you get an instance of Extract if you use the Extract constructor to construct the object. Otherwise, you get a plain old object, with the same properties as in the class, but not inheriting its methods. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Comment: I just read the link, but I still do not understand what's happening here. If I declare `extracts` as an array of `Extract` then I would have expected each element to be an instance of type `Extract`. If I'm simply populating the array with plain objects why do I even type the `extracts` array at all?

Comment: The array contains what you put in it. And the compiler won't let you put elements that are not Extracts, since you told the compiler that it's supposed to be an array of Extract. And you're trying to add elements that are not Extract instances, so the compiler complains. Neither the compiler nor the runtime can magically transform apples into oranges when you put apples in an array of oranges. That's the whole point of the TS compiler: it prevents you from doing things that don't make sense, like putting apples in an array of oranges.

Comment: I understand that, but why is it not complaining when I remove the method and only leave the properties? Is it simply because it can also be just a plain object?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error happens because the object literals that are included in the array don't match the *exact* type structure of the **Extract** class.

> First option:

To make it work with just a few changes, add as last property in each object the key **getReadableSchedule** and point it to method in the class prototype:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Find Barb",
    description: "Find Barb in the unspide down.",
    client: "Tower, Inc",
    vendor: "Vendy",
    extractType: "Normal",
    sentDate: "Today",
    path: "//outside",
    sentTo: "",
    lastRun: "",
    nextRun: "",
    schedule: "", 
    getReadableSchedule: Extract.prototype.getReadableSchedule// < -this will point to the same method in the class.
},
```

> Second option:

Just create an instance for each object, assign it to a variable, assign values to it's properties and then add that variable to the array, all objects created this way already have access to the method so no other change will be needed:

```
const EXTRACTS: Extract[] = [];

let a = new Extract();
a.propA = ...;
a.propB = ...;
.
.
.

EXTRACTS.push(a);

let b = new Extract();
b.propA = ...;
.
.
.
EXTRACTS.push(b);
```

> Third option:

If there is no intention to use the class as constructor, problably makes more sense to use an interface. So , outside of the class, declare a simple function equivalent to the class method...

```
export function getReadableSchedule(): string { 

    return "<return readable cronjob schedule>";
}
```

Inside the class, remove the body of the method leaving only the signature

```
getReadableSchedule(): string;
```

and change from ***class*** to ***interface*** in the type declaration and then export it.

```
export interface Extract {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now add object literals to EXTRACT array as done previously and the only thing that still is necessary to change is importing *getReadableSchedule* and adding it to each object:

```
import { Extract, getReadableSchedule } from "./extract";

const EXTRACTS: Extract[] = [
    {
        id: "whatever",
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        getReadableSchedule // <- this will point to the imported function
    } //<- and now all the properties are compatible with the type interface
];
```

The TypeScript type system checks only the **structure** of types. So the class...

```
class Extract {
    name: string;
    getReadableSchedule() {
        return "Some message";
    }        
}
```

has the following type structure ...

```
{
    name: string;
    getReadableSchedule(): string;
}
```

To assign an object literal for some variable of the type above,
that literal must have every property existent in the type and no other.

```
var fail1: Extract = { name: "1st failure" }; // does not type check - Missing property "getReadableSchedule"
var fail2: Extract = { getReadableSchedule() { return this.name; } }; // does not type check - Missing property "name";
var fail3: Extract = { // does not type check also! 
    name: "3rd failure", // Ok!
    getReadableSchedule() { return this.name } //Ok!
    id: 1 // Error - property "id" does not exist in type Extract
};

var success: Extract = { 
    name: "Success",
    getReadableSchedule() { return "Ok!"}
}; // <- No errors;

// But it is ok to assign a Variable that has all properties existent 
// in the type and additional ones

var notNamedType = {
    name: "Also works",
    getReadableSchedule() { return this.name },
    id: 1 // property does not exist in the Extract type but...
} 

let alsoWorks: Extract = notNamedType; // no casting needed and works as well;
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy response. I ended up (just this morning) moving the formatting to a Pipe and removing the method.

Comment: I hit this, for me it was second option - or do it property and don't force creation of the class with `{ id: 0 } as Extract`

Answer (score 0):

you may insert static before your function,

```
export class Extract {
....

 static getReadableSchedule(): string {
    return "<return readable cronjob schedule>";
  }
}
```

In this case, you can not use your instance in this function, so you may changt to this:

```
 static getReadableSchedule(e: Extract ): string {//use e
return "<return readable cronjob schedule>";



  }
```

Comment: It cannot be static, if you are going to use any instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

- Define your class;
- Create a const for your list, with only get/set variables, like a json content;
- Map your const to an another exportable const and assign all objects to your class;
- Access the link to view the full answer;
- Enjoy! ;P

```
class Foo {
    id!: number;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;

    get fullname(): string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
};

const INTERNAL_FOOS = [{...},{...}];

const FOOS: Foo[] = INTERNAL_FOOS.map(x => Object.assign(Foo.prototype, x));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQJYBMCEAXNAHYCuAtgEYCmATgNzqYBmWtEALgHJjnWHROtLMQDmjTNHCcefAUJHjUTDKOodozUiBDFe1ABQBKIgrEoVk6LXWlaxaAAMAJMg4ALLBAB0rdt30AX2hXDy9vaQC+QMcJTEDUQMZUYHhiTmgASS4AFQBRACUuAEEAGQB9WAB5KoBlaABeaABtNElcIgBGABpLPxl9IgAiWBEcId7JSNlqYYAhMFpKIcTui3acIgAmSZY2Ab5hhHgJy2nB6CGF2hXAgF1k1PSNarqiY+a7xqzcwpKK161bzkMAABwMAA9GgA+aBVSgAK2owA43kgECwomIBmO3lBtHgHEJAE9QdQ1hCjEZHmkIPAQNQIvBRDiarVmgAGO6+bS6fTUoA)